# Circular reference / retain cyle

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I am from Objective-c/Swift background and now working in Xamarin.iOS. I am having some confusion understanding circular reference (retain cycle in iOS env.).

Here is the piece of code I am working on.

```
public interface IHomeMoreTableViewSourceDelegate
{
    void RowSelected(int row);
}

public class HomeMoreTableViewSource: UITableViewSource
{
    public IHomeMoreTableViewSourceDelegate vDelegate;
}
```

ViewController code:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad() 
{
    HomeMoreTableViewSource source = new HomeMoreTableViewSource
    {
        vDelegate = this
    };
    MoreTableView.Source = source;
}
```

In Objective-C/Swift this would lead to a retain cycle and the way to break it is to add the keyword `weak` before the delegate variable declaration.

Would it also be a cicular reference in C#? If so how to break it? I saw [WeakReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.weakreference?view=netframework-4.7.2) but could not make much sense of it.

Comment: What happens when you compile it? The compiler will surely show you if you have a circurlar dependency. However it´s had to see for me. which classes references which other. I can´t see any circular reference here.

Comment: `ViewController` has a reference to `TableView`.`TableView` has a reference to `source`. `source` has a reference of `Interface/delegate`. `Interface/delegate` is referenced to `ViewController`.

Edit: It's compiling fine and working.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks.

Comment: You can post it as answer and accept it .So that more people will see it.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I'll do it after sometime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It´s absolutely fine for an object to reference another object which in turn references the first one. That´s the same as a father knowing his children, where every child of course knows its father. In this analogy you have a reference from the father to a child having a reference to the father.

```
class Father
{
    public List<Child> Children { get; } = new List<Child>();
}
class Child
{
    public Father Father { get; set; }
}
```

Now you could assign multiple children to your father:

```
var father = new Father();
father.Children.Add(new Child { Father = father });
```

In fact you could even have a class referencing itself:

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyClass TheInstance => this;
}
```

although this makes more sense for singletons where you want to ensure there´s allways only a single instance of your class. In this scenario `TheInstance` would be a `static` property.

A WeakReference btw. is something completely different.